# BigInsight Quick Start Edition 4.1 - BigSheet can't access HDFS from WebUI

Tags: hadoop, biginsights

I have started to use BigInsight Quick Start Edition 4.1 and the BigSheet Service.
I encountered following problem. 
I've started with this tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.tut.doc/doc/tut_Less_collSoclMediaData.html 
But I can't access the DFS Files from the BigSheets WebUI in my browser. I'm logged in as biadmin like recommended. 
The other Services are working correctly. And I can access the HDFS over the UI from Ambari Server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bluemix (cloud) or on your virtual machine ?

You can try doing impersonation of biadmin user and try your scenario.

Login to Ambari UI, then go to HDFS --> Config --> Advanced --> Custom core-site

Update or Add the property

hadoop.proxyuser.biadmin.groups=*

hadoop.proxyuser.biadmin.hosts=*

After changing the property, you need to restart the HDFS then restart the BigInsightsHome , BigSheet & Knox. Go to Knox and stop the Demo LDAP and start the Demo LDAP and try your scenario.

Comment: I'm using the virtual machine image. And I also tested the Docker Image, but with both I get problems. I will test your solution. Thanks

Comment: I tested your suggestion but I can't access DFS Files correctly. I did the following steps inside the VM.  

su hdfs 
hdfs dfs –chmod –R 777 / 

After this I could access the top-level directories of the hdfs like tmp or user but not the subdirectories of these folders.  In the WebUI of BigSheets I can't traverse the folders.

Any other suggestion?

Comment: After changing the property, you need to restart the HDFS then restart the BigInsightsHome , BigSheet & Knox. Go to Knox and stop the Demo LDAP and start the Demo LDAP and try your scenario.

Comment: I restarted all the components but my problem already exists. I can't access the subdirectories of the hdfs from the WebUi in New Workbook. Thanks for advices